# Cisco to Alcatel Config Converter

Tags: converters, config, cisco-ios

I am having a CISCO config file which needs to be converted to corresponding ALCATEL config ,can someone suggest something .

Answer (score 1):

Some Alcatel Lucent Switches and routers uses cli commands such 6450, 6350 etc. Then there are other such as SR 7750 which uses NetConf.
So direct conversion is not possible but may be you can just understand the and then configure other box with appropriate relevant commands.
Regards

Comment: Thanks @Dynamo ,yes finally i had to take help from Networking guys to convert it manuaaly.